# How to allow contract to transfer token from your wallet to others in erc721?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm new here really confused can anyone please tell me about the question

Scenario.

**Basically its a spinner game in which**

1. i have one master wallet which has tokens that are already minted.
2. The deployed contract address

**Now i want when any user wins the nft from spinner my contract itself send the token on master wallet behalf.**

How can i get this stuck here for soo much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the separate contract to allow or approve the contract to spend tokens dynamically